# draggable div problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this function to make my divs draggable and it works fine. right now if i have my mouse anywhere on the div it drags, but i only want it to drag the div if my mouse is on the rd_header div.  here is the function

```
        var makeDraggable = function(element) {

            element = jQuery(element);
            var move = function(event) {
                if(element.data('mouseMove')) {

                    var changeX = event.clientX - element.data('mouseX');
                    var changeY = event.clientY - element.data('mouseY');

                    var newX = parseInt(element.css('left')) + changeX;
                    var newY = parseInt(element.css('top')) + changeY;

                    element.css('left', newX);
                    element.css('top', newY);

                    element.data('mouseX', event.clientX);
                    element.data('mouseY', event.clientY);
                }
            }

            element.mousedown(function(event) {
                element.data('mouseMove', true);
                element.data('mouseX', event.clientX);
                element.data('mouseY', event.clientY);
            });

            element.parents(':last').mouseup(function() {
                element.data('mouseMove', false);
            });

            element.mouseout(move);
            element.mousemove(move);
        }
```

and i call it with this

```
makeDraggable(jQuery('#rd_main'));
```

i tried calling iot on the header div instead and changing the function variables element. to element.closest('div') but had no luck.  i would appreciate any help
here is my divs

```
<div id="rd_main">
    <div class="rd_header">Action Log</div>
    <div id="rd_logdiv" class="sb"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
makeDraggable('#rd_main', 'rd_header');
```

Then update your function with this:

```
var makeDraggable = function(element, triggerClass) {
    element = $(element);

    var move = function(event) {
            if (element.data('mouseMove') && isAvailable) {
                var changeX = event.clientX - element.data('mouseX');
                var changeY = event.clientY - element.data('mouseY');

                var newX = parseInt(element.css('left')) + changeX;
                var newY = parseInt(element.css('top')) + changeY;

                element.css('left', newX);
                element.css('top', newY);

                element.data('mouseX', event.clientX);
                element.data('mouseY', event.clientY);
            }
        },
        isAvailable = false;

    element.mousedown(function(event) {
        var target = $(event.target);

        isAvailable = target.hasClass(triggerClass) || target.closest('.' + triggerClass); //Check if we over wanted element
        element.data('mouseMove', true);
        element.data('mouseX', event.clientX);
        element.data('mouseY', event.clientY);
    });

    element.parents(':last').mouseup(function() {
        element.data('mouseMove', false);
    });

    element.mouseout(move);
    element.mousemove(move);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `element.children().first()` because `rd_header` div is the first child of your `rd_main`
div.

Any way why don't you use  Jquery draggable instead of your own function ? http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle

Comment: im using a chrome extension, and the jqueryui has many files... i was hoping to not have to include them all in the manifest.  i will try the children().first()  that sounds like it may work